# Shiny: need finite 'ylim' values, but no NA values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to set up a Shiny app with the following code being run on the menarche dataset from the MASS package:

```
##ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Probability of menarche among adolescent girls in Warsaw, 1965"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("men_Age", "What is the age of menarche?", 
                        9, 18, value = 12),
            submitButton("Submit")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plot("plot1"),
            h3("Probability of menarche:"),
            textOutput("pred1")
        )
    )
))
##server.R
library(shiny)
library(MASS)
data(menarche)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    mprob <- glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age, 
             family = binomial(link = probit), data = menarche)
    modelPred <- reactive({
        menInput <- input$men_Age
        x <- predict(mprob, newdata = data.frame(Age = menInput))
        exp(x)/(1+exp(x))
    })
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        menInput <- input$men_Age
        plot(menarche$Age, menarche$Menarche / menarche$Total, 
             xlab = "Age of menarche onset", ylab = "Pr(Menarche)",
             bty = "n", pch = 16, xlim = c(9, 18), ylim = c(0, 1))
        lines(menarche$Age, mprob$fitted, type = "l", col = "blue", lwd=2)
        points(menInput, modelPred(), pch = 16, col = "blue", cex = 2)
    })
    output$pred1 <- renderText({
      modelPred()
    })
  })
```

I have run the plot code separately and saw that it worked. However, when I tried to run the app, I was getting an error of "need finite 'ylim' values". I set finite ylim values, so I don't know what is going on. I had read some other posts that mentioned NA values, but the menarche dataset does not have any NA values. It looks like they are getting coerced according to this output:

```
Warning in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'ylim' values
Stack trace (innermost first):
    57: plot.window
    56: localWindow
    55: plot.default
    54: plot
    53: tag
    52: tags$div
    51: div
    50: mainPanel
    49: sidebarLayout
    48: tag
    47: tags$div
    46: div
    45: tagList
    44: attachDependencies
    43: bootstrapPage
    42: fluidPage
    41: shinyUI
     1: runApp
Error : need finite 'ylim' values
```

But removing any reference to the plot from both ui and server files allows the app to run smoothly. Does anyone know what I may be missing?

Comment: Going through your code it looks like the error is due to the element in your ui .  `mainPanel` of your ui the element should be`plotOutput` instead of `plot`. Hope this remove the error.

Comment: Thanks. I also saw that I was using the wrong inverse. It should be pnorm(x) rather than the inverse logit.